# Hue doesn't find specific words

Tags: solr, lucene, cloudera, hue

I've been indexing files using cloudera CDH 5.0 and Solr version 4.4 for some time and I have been getting some weird select results. For example, for the specific word `"odi"` it doesn't find any match, though it does exist in the files I am indexing, but it finds it when I use `*odi or odi*`. I've checked for special chars before and after that word and it just has blank spaces on both sides.

Has anyone experienced something similar? If so what have you done to solve it?

Here is the schema default configuration:

```xml
 <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
   <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
   <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
   <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
   -->
   <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal. -->
   <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" />
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
   <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
   <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
   -->
   <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
   <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
   <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" />
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
   <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
   <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
   -->
   <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
 </fieldType>
```

Comment: Probably an analysis issue.  Can you provide the `fieldType` definition for the field?

Comment: filedType is set to text

Comment: No, the definition of the "text" fieldType.  You're looking for: `<fieldType name="text"......`

Comment: I will be editing the filed definition as it is on the schema on the main post.

Comment: This is most probably a Solr collection configuration issue. You can also look at the default solrconfig used by Hue: https://github.com/cloudera/hue/tree/master/apps/search/examples/collections